# Android Manifest <uses-configuration>

Tags: android, manifest, android-manifest

I've finished writing the first version of my app and I'm trying to set the manifest correctly.

My app is a game that uses the touch

so I want to make sure that the phone handles touch

so I set the following:

```
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"/>
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="finger"/>
```

Now what I'm wondering is do I need to put stylus ? would a game that works with touch work with stylus?

I don't have a stylus android phone handy so I would like to have some input if I should use this or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time yes. There are cases, though, where a stylus will not work (if you require multitouch, for instance).

Instead of defining multiple configurations, however, a more correct (and simpler) solution for the use case you specify would be:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
```

If you require multitouch, you can state:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> > would a game that works with touch work with stylus?

Yes.

Keep in mind that 99% of the android handsets will have touchscreen... so most of the times you won't have to worry about `reqTouchScreen`.